# Merge the ins file into dtx file

Tags: literate-programming, iffalse

The following demo (file name `demo.dtx`) is used to demonstrate how to merge `.ins` file into `.dtx` in literate programming:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
some readme contents
%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\begingroup
  \def\temp{LaTeX2e}
\expandafter\endgroup\ifx\temp\fmtname\else
\csname fi\endcsname
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip %
\generate{
  \nopreamble\nopostamble
  \file{README.md}{\from{demo.dtx}{readme}}}
\endbatchfile
%</install>
%<*internal>
\fi
%</internal>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
  \PrintChanges
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \title{\LaTeX~Literate Programming}
% \author{Jack}
% \maketitle
```

Running `tex demo.dtx` will extract the `README.md` file while running `pdflatex demo.dtx` will produce the documentation (currently there is only the title and author, just for demonstration).

I think the code fragment:

```
\begingroup
  \def\temp{LaTeX2e}
\expandafter\endgroup\ifx\temp\fmtname\else
\csname fi\endcsname
```

is the key point since it can conduct different tasks by judging the format. But I'm a little confused about the detailed and precise process when `demo.dtx` is compiled by different formats especially the pairing of `\iffalse` and `\fi`.

Can someone give some explanations? Thanks!

Comment: it's possible  but I don't really recommend it, we do this less and less. having the sources contain obscure `\fi` balancing tricks somewhat works against the "literate programming" ideal

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion@DavidCarlisle. I just want to analyze the tricks used here.

Comment: yes I'll probably answer later,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is how to skip conditionals.

If you want to skip some code containing `\fi` you can not do

```
\iffalse
   \foo
   \bar
   \fi
   \hmm
\fi
```

as, despite the indent, the `\iffalse` matches the first `\fi`.

`\csname fi\endcsname` expands to `\fi` so can be used (sometimes) to hide a `\fi` from an outer conditional.

However you can only sometimes use `\csname fi\endcsname`:

```
\iftrue
  hello
\csname fi\endcsname
```

has matching `if` and `fi` and prints `hello` but

```
\iftrue
  hello
\else
  goodbye
\csname fi\endcsname
```

will skip the rest of the document looking for `\fi` as after the `\else` tex will be scanning for `\fi` without expansion.

In docstrip things are made more interesting as `%` is or is not a comment, depending on the mode.

so....

**if you do `pdflatex demo.dtx`**

`%` is a comment so `% \iffalse` on line 1 is not seen,
`\iffalse` on line 3 matches `\fi` on line 9.
`\ifx` on line 12 is `\iftrue` so  `\else` branch skipped
`\csname fi\endcsname` on line 13 is skipped
`\fi` on line 23 closes the `\ifx`
`\documentclass{ltxdoc}` is processed
`\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}` inputs the file again but `%` is not a comment.

---

`\iffalse` on line 1 is seen, starts skipping
`\iffalse` adds to the fi nesting that must be skipped
`\csname fi\endcsname` on line 13 not seen as `\fi`
`\fi` on line 23 removes one level of if-fi nesting
`\fi` on line 33 closes the `\iffalse` on line 1 and skipping stops.
`\title`, `\author` and `\maketitle` executed.

---

---

**If you do `pdftex demo.dtx`**

works as above until  `\ifx` on line 12.
`\ifx` is `\iffalse` so after `\else` expansion enabled
`\csname fi\endcsname` seen as `\fi` and ends the `\ifx`
`\input docstrip` is executed on line 16
`\generate` will input `demo.dtx` in verbatim mode where none of the `\if` are executed
control returns to line 19
`\endbatchfile` on line 20 does `\@@end` and ends the job
the `\fi` on line 23 is therefore not seen.